# how to load textures with openGL and show on surface

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have images in drawable folder, i have to show images on surfaceview with help of OpenGL

i want to use textures for image loading.

please, tell how can i simply show images(using texture) on surfaceView with openGL.

Answer (score 1):

please go through this,

http://blog.jayway.com/2010/12/30/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-vi-textures/

this is very useful link.

Comment: I'm sure he would be better off starting this linked tutorial from the beginning, as he seems never to have heard anything of OpenGL.